# How to use multiple database connection with one model dynamically in sailsjs?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am beginner in sailsjs, i have multiple databases but table structure is same. So i would like to use single model and controller for all these databases.

I know we can set connection attribute in model like this

```
module.exports = {
    connection: 'mysqlServer1',
    attributes: {
    userid: {
        type: 'integer',
        primaryKey: true
    },
    fbid: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    source: {
        type: 'string'
    }
   }    
 }
};
```

But how can we set connection dynamically runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I stumbled on it looking for a solution to different problem, thought I'd answer.

The simplest way is to just set environment variables and use defaults.

For example, if you put `MODELA_CONN="mysqlServer1"` in your `.bash_profile`, or lift sails with an export like `export MODELA_CONN="mysqlServer1" && sails lift`, then you can just use that:

```
module.exports = {
  connection: process.env.MODELA_CONN || "defaultMysql",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this isn't possible yet. The closest thing you can get to a dynamic connection is using the following npm package https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-autoreload.
This will automatically reload sailjs with the changed connection config, without to lift sails again. But it won't cover your problem during runtime.